# How to add data into association table in sequelize without creating a new record?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to add records into my tables. I am using create for that.
I have two tables USERS and GROUPS with a many to many relationship(auto created users_groups). This is the code I have written

```
const [instance, created] = await models.USERS.create({
  userName: userName,
  userId: userId,
  lastName: lastName,
  GROUPS: [
   {
      groupId: 123,
      groupName: "abc"
   },
   {
      groupId: 345,
      groupName: "def"
   }
 ],
 }, {
   include: {
   model: models.GROUPS
  },
});
```

Here userId is unique for USERS table and groupId is unique for GROUPS. Primary key for USERS is userPK and for GROUPS it is groupsPK.
The first time the create works well. If I run the same create code but with different GROUP data I am getting an error

```
const [instance, created] = await models.USERS.create({
  userName: userName,
  userId: userId,
  lastName: lastName,
  GROUPS: [
   {
      groupId: 999,
      groupName: "hjk"
   }
 ],
 }, {
   include: {
   model: models.GROUPS
  },
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: duplicate key value violates  unique constraint "u_s_e_r_s_u_s_e_r_i_d"
```

Why does this error come. Why isn't sequelize considering that existing row in USERS table and adding into GROUPS table?
I remove unique constraint on USERS table and followed the same procedure,  in that case two same records gets added into USERS table with 1st record pointing to 1st create call and 2nd record pointing to 2nd create call although both the records in USER are same
How do I go about this issue?

Comment: The code is attempting to insert a new user row because that is what `CREATE` does. Adding a new group to an existing user is an `UPDATE` operation.

Comment: @JohnH I have tried update as well but the only problem with update is that the record gets added into GROUPS table but the mapping table is not getting updated.